# java.util.concurrent.TimeOutException while trying to launch Wildfly server

Tags: hibernate, wildfly-10, timeoutexception

I am receiving the following error while trying to deploy war file in Wildfly server.

[Wildfly error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFZgt.jpg)

Tried increasing the timeout parameter in standalone.config file. But didn't work. 
Earlier, I was able to deploy the same. But, I had made few changes to the code, that's when this problem started. I commented all the code that might have caused the issue and tried deploying again. But, no luck!

Comment: try to clean up your wildfly temporary folders.

Comment: How big is your deployment?